# $_FILES não funciona

Tags: php

EDIT: Mesmo colocando a tag ENCTYPE no form, o problema persiste.
Estou tentando utilizar o `$_FILES` pela primeira vez, e estou enfrentando dificuldades. É como se ele não recebesse nada. Vejam o código que estou utilizando.

HTML:

```
<form id="formtiles" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="scripts/cadastro.php" >
    <label for="logo"><b>Logotipo: </b></label>
    <input name="logo" type="file" id="logo" data-mini="true"/>
    <input type="submit" form="formtiles" value="Gravar"  id="enviadadoscliente" data-inline="true" data-icon="check"/>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$location = 'public_html/teste/grid/img';
if (isset($_FILES['logo'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['logo']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['logo']['tmp_name'];

    $error = $_FILES['logo']['error'];
    if ($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo 'Erro ao fazer o upload:', $error;
    } elseif (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
        echo 'Uploaded';    
    }
}
```

Grato desde já pela ajuda.

Comment: Para o $_FILES funcionar, a princípio, no seu form deve conter: <form enctype= "multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coloque na tag `form`:
`entype="multipart/form-data"`

EDIT:

Provavelmente a pasta de destino da imagem (`public_html/teste/grid/img`) está errada, você deve acessa-la respeitando a hierarquia de pastas exemplo, seu arquivo php está na pasta: 
`public_html/teste/php`

Então seu caminho até a pasta `img` deve ser:

```
../grid/img/
```

Sou o arquivo `php`, estou na pasta `php`, e meu caminho está uma pasta atrás da minha, logo tenho que voltar uma pasta (com `../`) para poder ver a pasta `grid` e consequentemente a `img`.

**Dica:**

Sugiro usar a função `time()` para gerar nomes de imagens, pois se o usuário fizer upload de duas imagens com o mesmo nome poderá ocorrer um erro, mude a variável `$name` para:

```
$name = time().".jpg";
```

**Link de download do exemplo:** [MEGA NZ](https://mega.co.nz/#!AxBCSICB!SUykboa8oTeZb7NJwZFTfcZ13BsUovuoavAc8tQqSn0)

Comment: Boa tarde, na verdade eu coloquei essa tag também no form, mas foi logo após a minha postagem. Continuou não funcionando. Você tem alguma outra sugestão?

Comment: Ele provavelmente não está encontrado a pasta `public_html/teste/grid/img` você deve fazer como caminhos de HTML e CSS, ir voltando as pastas com `../` até chegar a um grau que possa acessar a pasta img. Irei colocar na resposta.

Comment: Não é isso também. O problema é que o $_FILES não está recebendo nada. Ele nem chega a entrar no if (isset($_FILES['logo']))

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Infelizmente não aparece nada. Apenas vem vazio o valor do $_FILES.

Comment: Dá uma verificada nos caminhos, certamente o erro é esse, eu fiz um teste aqui, apenas copiei e colei o código e mudei o caminho de acordo com minha estrutura de pastas... Verifique se o `submit` do `form` esteja indo realmente para o arquivo `cadastro.php`. Em seguida verifique o caminho da variável `$location` (esse sim está esranho)

Comment: o arquivo do formulário está em qual pasta? Outro problema que notei, foi a ausência de `/` no fim da variável `$location` assim ele não está gravando o arquivo dentro da pasta e sim um arquivo chamado `img+nome-da-imagem` na pasta `grid`

Comment: De fato o caminho estava errado sim. Porém persiste o erro. Inclusive todos os POSTs funcionam e recebem valores, apenas com o $_FILES é que não dá certo.

Comment: Coloquei na resposta um link de download  de um exemplo perfeitamente igual ao seu código, aqui ele funcionou tudo ok.. Se não funcionar aí o problema é no software utilizado para simular o servidor. Se funcionar analise o código e adapte-se no seu. Ás vezes ele pode exibir um `Warning` falando que não pode receber arquivo por parâmetro, mas é apenas um `Warning`, nada que obstrua o funcionamento do código.

Comment: Leonardo, descobri qual é o problema. A questão é que estou usando o JQuery Mobile, e ele embute ajax nos formularios. Isso gera erro no upload de arquivos, portanto para funcionar eu tive que colocar a tag data-ajax="false" no form. Mas só descobri isso após analisar o código que voce anexou e comparando ele com o meu. Muito obrigado pelo apoio!